# In Electron why is my second breakpoint not getting hit?

Tags: javascript, debugging, visual-studio-code, electron

Using Electron I'm currently wanting to debug in Visual Studio Code.

My code looks like this

```
app.on("ready", createWindow);

app.on("ready",() => {
  theSQL.createDatabase();
  theSQL.createTables();
});
```

When i set a break point for the first `app.on("ready)` the debugger activates. 
However if i set a break point for the next `app.on("ready", () => (sql code));`.

The debugger doesn't stop at the break point.

Am i missing something?

e.g. is having two app.on readys not a good idea?

Comment: `ready` event only fires once so your second `ready` eventhandler will never invoke, reason debugger won't hit there ever.

Comment: but the code inside of the second ready event does get executed?